# How to convert charts back to price data?

Tags: python

I have a weird question, we normally generate charts - line, bar, candlestick etc from price data. But if we have a chart, how to convert back to price data?

```
def plot_candlestick_and_multiple_lines(data, filename, line_list):
    
    # Create figure and set axes for subplots
    fig = plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(10, 10), dpi=50, facecolor='w') 
    
    ax_candle = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    
    # Plot candlestick chart
    candlestick_ohlc(ax_candle, zip(data.index, data['open'], data['high'], data['low'], data['close']), colordown='red',colorup='green', width=0.5)
    
    for l in line_list:
        ax_candle.plot(data.index, data[l])
        
    ax_candle.grid(False)
    ax_candle.set_xticks([])
    ax_candle.set_yticks([])
    ax_candle.axis('off')    
    
    plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches="tight")
    #plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking how to grab number data from a rendered chart? You have the `data` variable, which I assume is your price data.

Comment: You are right.  That is a weird question.  Clarify!

Comment: this is a weird and very interesting question. after rendering the graph is in the form of an image. so, if we want to extract data from that image we have to implement a graph reading image processing system.

Comment: if you have chart as image with numbers then you may need OCR program (like Tesseract or module PyTesseract) to recognize text on image. Eventually it may need more complex Neural Netowork to recognize values on images. Or you need to create more complex code which recognize bars on image and measure sizes. If you have chart on web page then usually data are somewhere in `JavaScript` or directly in HTML or they are read from server as JSON.

Comment: @Kirk, yes if we have price data, we can build a chart. How comes we do not have price data, only have chart, how to convert back to price data?

Comment: @furas, thank you. I will try that.

Comment: good luck - you will need a lot of knowledge for this - and you may need to ask on similar portal for [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) and/or for [Computer Vision](https://forum.opencv.org/) (`CV`)

Comment: how about creating your charts as SVG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics ? this will make it pretty easy to parse the SVG and get the original data.